# What are the conditions to be $f(x)=\,$(inverse of $x$ in a group) continuous?

Tags: group-theory, continuity

Lets be an interval $\varDelta\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and a group $(G,*)$ ($\varDelta\subseteq G$). I believe that if $f(x)=u*x$ ($D_f =G$) is continuous (usual topology) for all $u\in G$, then $g(x)=x^{-1}$ ($x*x^{-1}=1_*$) is also continuous.

1. Is that true?
2. Is there any bibliography about properties of continuous groups like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "an interval $G$"? Are you considering $G\subseteq \mathbb R$ with the usual topology?

Comment: @Christoph, yes, I forgot to write it. I 'll edit my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What exactly is $G$? Open interval? Closed interval? Mixed? Also what is $*$? It cannot be the standard multiplication because no interval (except for $\{1\}=[1,1]$) in $\mathbb{R}$ is a group under it. And if it is an arbitrary group multiplication then it may or may not be continuous. It depends on the definition. Also if one end of $G$ belongs to $G$ (i.e. $G$ is not an open interval) then no topological group structure exists on $G$. Because it is not a homogenous space.

Comment: I think the question can be reformulated as follows: if $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with a group law $\ast$ which is continuous on one side, is it a topological group law? (It makes no difference to work with an open interval or $\mathbb{R}$, and as @freakish said, a closed or semi-closed interval cannot be a topological group anyway.)

Comment: @freakish if $(G,*)=((0,+\infty),\cdot)$, then $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

Comment: @CaptainLama, I changed some things. I 'm really sorry.

Comment: @Christoph , https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Multiplicative_Group_of_Positive_Real_Numbers

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας Right, I wasn't paying attention. $(0,\infty)$ with multiplication is isomorphic as a topological group to $\mathbb R$ with addition by taking logarithms. I think Captain Lama is asking the right question.

Comment: Over reals $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is automatically continuous if $*:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. This is stronger than your assumption. This follows from the fact that every locally compact paratopological group is in fact a topological group: O. V. Ravsky, "The topological and algebraic properties of paratopological groups", Proposition 5.5.

Comment: @freakish, thanks a lot!!! Is that a book or an article. I cant't find it.

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας it's his PhD thesis. The same can be found in Mikhail Tkachenko, "Paratopological and Semitopological Groups Versus Topological Groups", Theorem 3.3.